# Regex checking for Numbers and Alphabets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match strings which contain only having numbers with comma and numbers with hyphens like,

Should match,

```
   22-10,3,34-2,16
   22,10,3,34,2,16
   22-10-3-34-2-16
   23-10,6
```

Should not match,

```
   4ABS-NTts
   ABS,NT
   2
```

Any help would be very helpful

Comment: I'm not very good at regex, but I'd like to share a link with you where you can test regex and find examples uploaded by users: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: why should it not match `2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:[0-9]+[,-])+[0-9]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(?:       # Try to match:
 [0-9]+   #  one or more digits
 [,-]     #  one separator (- or ,)
)+        # once or more.
[0-9]+    # Match one or more digits
$         # End of string
```

Comment: It will match empty string and 2 also.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't see that numbers alone are not OK. Will edit.

Comment: it does not math bare numbers like `22`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(?:\d+[,-]?)+\d+$
```

it matches bare numbers like `23` too.
You can test it in [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Comment: I am upvoting for your effort, but the criteria is only numbers with hyphen and comma should match